# Modifying foreign Workspaces in RCP Apps

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm working on an RCP program that I want to use to modify an Eclipse Workspace that I determine at runtime (to set preferences, import projects, etc), but I haven't found a way to access foreign Workspaces in my RCP app. I know that my own RCP App is running inside a workspace, and that I can get access to this Workspace through the Resource Plugin. I've also read through several tutorials on how to switch the active workspace, but all the methods I have seen either must be done at launch or require a restart, and so don't fit my runtime usecase very well.

Is there a way for me to modify a foreign Eclipse workspace with the Eclipse API, or do I have to resort to file-level changes and manually modify .metadata and .project files?

Edit: I changed the design of my program to only require an Eclipse Workspace prompt at the start.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to work with a different workspace. Manually modifying the workspace is likely to cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: You could start a second instance of your RCP to work on the workspace.

Comment: Manually editing Eclipse Preferences is relatively straightforward, so long as you know where in the .metadata folder the given preference is stored. Manually importing projects sounds rather tricky, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the design of my program to only use Eclipse Workspace prompts at launch. If the user wants to access a foreign workspace, the program automatically restarts to make this possible. The solution is not ideal, but it worked for me.

Linked is [the reference I found most useful](http://hexapixel.com/2009/01/12/rcp-workspaces) for this.